# Unity 2020.3.33f1 SceneManager.sceneLoaded never call?

Tags: unity-game-engine

This code is never call (only the OnEnable/onDisable), why? It looks like this is an issue in Unity? I tried it in Start/Awake, same behaviour:

```
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded += OnSceneLoaded;
        Debug.Log("OnEnable");
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded -= OnSceneLoaded;
        Debug.Log("OnDisable");
    }

    private static void OnSceneLoaded(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnSceneLoaded: " + scene.name);
        _canRun = true;
    }
```

Comment: Your code works for me. I tried static and non-static delegates to make sure. How do you load these scenes? Via script? Is that Object in a "Don't Destroy On Load"? Or do you use LoadSceneMode.Additive ? Otherwise your script will not survive the load and the function cannot be called.

Comment: @KYL3R I tried in instance, and tried in normal classes too. Neither worked. 
I just open a scene and wait for load. So basically I just run the code, not loading a new scene

Comment: @KYL3R what version of unity did you tried? I do anything the callback never call.. In Awake, or Start or other...in instance or in simple monobehavior that active....

Comment: "I just open a scene and wait for load. " what do you mean? You open a scene manually? Is the game running? Maybe you need `[ExecuteInEditMode]` ?

Comment: @KYL3R it is working on a brand new project. But not on my 96 GB project. LOL. Any idea why? The same script, I just copy pasted the code. :D

Answer (score 1):

Because `OnDisable` is called before `OnSceneLoaded` (this method is called after `Awake` in the new scene), if you want to remove the listenser, you can do it in `OnSceneLoaded` method, notice to check the scene name.

```
private static void OnSceneLoaded(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode)
{
    Debug.Log("OnSceneLoaded: " + scene.name);
    if(scene.name == "......")
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded -= OnSceneLoaded;
    _canRun = true;
}
```

---

Update test code

```
public class TestLoad : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded += OnSceneLoaded;
        Debug.Log("OnEnable");
    }

    private static void OnSceneLoaded(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnSceneLoaded: " + scene.name);
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: If I remove the OnDisable part, the same behaviour will be

Comment: what version of unity did you tried? I do anything the callback never call.. In Awake, or Start or other...in instance or in simple monobehavior that active....

Comment: I just downloaded 2020.3.33f1, ran the above test code with a basic scene. When the game was played, I could see `OnSceneLoaded` after `OnEnable` in the console.

Comment: it is working on a brand new project. But not on my 96 GB project. LOL. Any idea why? The same script, I just copy pasted what you created. :D

Comment: With a brand new scene?

Comment: It's an event, so it is able to remove a listener by `-=` operator or reflection. You may try `sceneUnload` and `activeSceneChanged` events to see if they work.

Comment: when I load a new scene from the first it is working in the big project, but first time not...

Comment: I tried sceneUnload and activeSceneChanged, these are the same behaviours like the first. So first time not working. But when from code load a new scene, on the second scene, working.

Comment: So now we can confirm that these events are working, the problem must be the registered listeners are removed or cleared by some scripts. The evil might be a third-party library I guess. If you are using a version control software, you may test from historical versions. Another idea is using some assembly editor (reflexil, dotpeek, ...) to modify coremodule.dll and replace the event with your custom code, this is what I did once I was trying to find out who changed the position of a transform.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your Project Settings (*Edit*/*Project Settings*) - under the *Editor* tab you will find the **Enter Play Mode Settings** option.

[image]

As long as this option is disabled, or both this and the **Reload Scene** option are enabled, the sceneLoaded event should be triggered as expected. If you enable **Enter Play Mode Options** but disable **Reload Scene**, the editor apparently does not fully "load" the scene which in turn prevents the sceneLoaded event from triggering.

(IIRC disabling this option is one of the recommended settings to speed up switching from editor to play mode but it seems to have unwanted side effects)